# Route with parameter in ASP.NET Web API using OWIN OAuthAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to use a route like "/api/{culture}/token" for my OAuth authorization process at my Web API but I'm not succeeding on it.

```
 var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/{culture}/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };
```

I have seen how to access query string parameters as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442364/owin-oauth-send-additional-parameters) but it would be better to call this route as, say, api/en-US/token instead of api/token/?auth_parameters&culture=en-US