# Best way to add and retrieve new post parameters to the GrantRefreshToken() in OWIN Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

the default request parameters to get new JWT using refresh token are:
grant_type , refresh_token and client_id .

I need to control the claims identity modification by adding new body parameter when requesting a new refresh token.

let say the parameter is named by grant_claims, which can hold true or false boolean value.

how can I get that custom parameter in the GrantRefreshToken() overridden method?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer from this post :

[owin oauth send additional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442364/owin-oauth-send-additional-parameters)

in the `ValidateClientAuthentication` we can add additional params

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
   // other code ...
       var grantClaims = context.Parameters.Get("grant_claims");
    // other code ...
        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("grant_claims", grantClaims);
    // other code ...
}
```

then get the values in the authentication and refresh token methods

```
// auth
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var grantClaims = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("grant_claims");

}

//refresh token
public override async Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
        {
var grantClaims = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("grant_claims");
}
```